# Failed to connect by IP address to an SQL Server, Error code 1312

Tags: sql-server, windows, database-connection

I have to change my notebook to a new one. And I get this error :

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to xxx.xxx.x.xx.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1312)
>
> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

The question is: why can't I connect to the database on my server (a physical server, not a notebook or PC) by IP address on this new notebook, while on the old I was able to do so?

I already tried to export and import the settings from my old notebook and following those steps written in this [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1c1b037-6c70-444f-9066-012ee5b9d20e/i-cant-connect-remotely-to-sql-server-with-ip-however-i-can-locally?forum=sqlexpress) too but nothing has changed.

All services is enabled, `TCP/IP = Enabled`, Both `port` has a default `1433` value, `Named Pipes = yes`

My old notebook has Windows 7 with default SQL Server installation, and my new notebook has the same too, but I decided to upgrade the OS to Windows 10 because I think it will fix the problem.

Now I have Windows 10 installed with No security software installed and Force disabling Firewall by Registry so it doesn't block the connection. But the problem is still there.

Could somebody help, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution but it's kinda ridiculous, I logged out my Microsoft Account and it works. But I still hope someone can explain why this can be happened. So if you guys have another solution, please put some here so I can learn it more about and to fix this error in another method.